# Html 5 pattern regex and minimum

Tags: javascript, regex, html

I want a pattern that accepts a minimum of 8 characters and letters and numbers whether uppercase or lowercase but no white spaces or special characters.
I tried searching for similar regex but most don't go with what I want.
Here's my regex

```
 pattern="[A-Za-z0-9].{8,}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the dot, which matches any character:

```
pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]{8,}"
```

with your pattern you accept one alphanumeric character followed by at least eight "any" characters.

Comment: Thx this solved my problem. But may I ask why the ^ and $ are there? Just in case someone else wants to know.

Comment: They are not necessary in pattern attribute, but normally they mean beginning and end of string.

Answer (score 0):

According to [`pattern` attribute documentation](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/semantics.html#the-pattern-attribute):

> This regular expression language used for this attribute is the same
>   as that used in JavaScript, except that the pattern attribute is
>   matched against the entire value, not just any subset (somewhat as if
>   it implied a `^(?:` at the start of the pattern and a `)$` at the end).

Thus, you can also use the following regex:

```
pattern = "[A-Za-z\d]{8,}"
```

Also [note that](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp)

> The pattern attribute works with the following input types: `text`,
>   `search`, `url`, `tel`, `email`, and `password`.